# How to access namespace in Business Access Layer

Tags: c#

How to access this namespace using System.Web.UI.WebControls; in business access layer.
How to add reference of this namspace? Plz help me..

Comment: You should be aware that this will couple your Business Layer to a Web UI. If that is undesired.. you should rethink your design. If it is desired.. I would ask why you're separating your assemblies in the first place.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you want to say??

Comment: The ["BLL"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic) and ["DAL"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) have *little reason* to access the WebControls namespace, which is related to the UI. This "issue" likely  represents a problem with leaking concerns, even if it can be resolved without fixing such design ..

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not good add System.Web.UI.WebControls but if you want you can use:

[See](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx):

In **Solution Explorer**, double-click the My Project node for the project.

In the Project Designer, click the **References tab**.

Click the Add button to open the **Add Reference dialog** box.

In the Add Reference dialog box, select the **tab indicating the type of component you want to reference**.

Select the components you want to reference, and then **click OK**.

Answer (score 1):

You must reference System.Web assembly:

```
Namespace:  System.Web.UI.WebControls
Assembly:  System.Web (in System.Web.dll)
```

Answer (score 1):

From business layer you means a web service you calling from your UI project, you should not call UI logic from your Business layer, because separating it in two different project is the reason that your UI logic should be separate from your business logic. So if needed you can easily change complete UI.

If you want to be dependent on UI logic then there is no need to make separate project. You can create a folder in UI project for BLL and add your code there.